# When I set NHibernate "adonet.batch_size" the sql not logged any more

Tags: nhibernate, logging

When I set both:

```
show_sql = true
adonet.batch_size = 100
```

the INSERT/UPDATE SQL statements are not logged any more. Can this be fixed some how?

Comment: I have the same problem. Anyone has a solution?